# Text substitutions not working

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

It's common that I post an answer that includes keyboard formatting.

So if I type `<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>` it shows up in the answer as <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, as I'm sure many of you know.

Well, I got tired of typing `<kbd></kbd>` every time I want to describe a *letter*; so I set up a text substitution in OS X in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Text* so that I can just type `xkbd` and it will be converted to `<kbd></kbd>`.

...Except that Stack Exchange's text input fields reject text substitutions, so it doesn't convert. I assume this is to fight spam bots, but it's also getting in the way of functionality. **Please allow established users to use text substitution.**

Comment: I doubt it's SE's doing, to prove/disprove it can you try and add those things in the textarea [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wocg8q71/)?

Comment: Why would this have anything to do with "spam bots"?

Comment: What browser are you using? As far as I can tell, the text substitution feature isn't just using the feature - you have to turn it on for *every single app* you want to use the feature, and [Safari is currently the only browser which lets you do that](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179187/turn-on-text-replacement-chrome). But alas, this has nothing to do with us. We do not disable any of the auto* features in our HTML structure. If it's not working, it's your computer.

Comment: Check this: http://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts

Comment: @Doorknob Because text can be entered without actually typing it. This was my guess.

Comment: @brasofilo Thank you! Looks like a good solution.

Comment: @animuson Sorry for jumping to conclusions. I'll reword my post title. How disappointing that other browsers don't support it (or is it that Apple only granted access to Safari?). I just skimmed through the link you posted - will research in more detail when I can. (I'm using Firefox.)

Comment: I'm closing this for now since it doesn't look like we're doing anything to *prevent* this from working. I wish we could control what browsers are supported... but alas, we aren't quite *that* important yet. :)